# How can I re-write this for-loop with lapply

Tags: r, for-loop, lapply

I'm trying to replace my for loop in R with lapply.

```
Table <- c("Filepath1","Filepath2")
Conditions c<- c("Yes","No")

for (i in 1:length(Table)){

Df[[i]] <- readxl::read_xlsx(Table[i])
Df[[i]]$Condition <- Conditions[i]

}
```

So this takes the first element in Table, reads it into R and then adds a column to the table corresponding to the first element in Conditions.

using lapply I can add the tables in by:

```
lapply(Table, readxl::read_xlsx)
```

I could say:

```
Df[[1]]$Conditions <- Conditions[1]
Df[[2]]$Conditions <- Conditions[2]
```

But how do I add this extra column in without the use of for-loops?

Comment: Something like : `lapply(seq_along(Conditions), function(x)
  {res <- read_excel(list.files(pattern = ".*xlsx")[x])
  res$Cond <- Conditions[x] 
  head(res)
})`. This assumes equal lengths for the files table and conditions vector. It also assumes that you have everything in the same directory.

Comment: You can replace read_excel with read_xlsx. I actually used `read.csv` locally because I have no xlsx files available. :)

Comment: I like your answer :) but unfortunately the files are in different directories.

Comment: Replace list.files with the vector with the filepaths.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate through both objects (table and condition) using `mapply`. Untested:

```
mapply(FUN = function(tbl, cnd) {
  out <- readxl::read_excel(tbl)
  out$Condition <- cnd
  out
}, tbl = Table, cnd = Conditions)
```

Comment: You are missing the parameters. Also, look into `transform` or `within` for a one-liner.

Comment: Bah, you are right about the parameters. I don't care much for one-liners, sorry.